# for loop select construction jq in bash

Tags: json, bash, jq

required help
need get the name value from id
my bash script
cant get it to work

```sh
#!/bin/bash

array=( "111" "222" etc...)

for i in "${array[@]}"; do
   my_power=$(
      curl -s -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://website/list |
         jq -r '.magic[] | select(.id == "$i") | .name'
   )
   echo "$my_power"
   magic_array+=( "$my_power" )
done
```

`$magic_array` is empty. The `echo` prints nothing.

```sh
curl -s -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://website/list
```

outputs the following all on one line:

```json
{
  "magic": [
    {
      "name": "fly",
      "links": {
        "self": "http://website/111"
      },
      "tags": null,
      "enabled": true,
      "id": "111",
      "description": null
    },
    {
      "name": "sleep",
      "links": {
        "self": "http://website/222"
      },
      "tags": null,
      "enabled": true,
      "id": "222",
      "description": null
    }
  ],
  "links": {
    "self": "http://website/list",
    "previous": null,
    "next": null
  }
}
```

Direct request from command line work perfect

```
$ curl -s -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://website/list |
   jq -r '.magic[] | select(.id == "111") | .name'
fly
```

Comment: This might help: [Difference between single and double quotes in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753/3776858)

Comment: If there are n items in the list, the approach shown in the Q will require n redundant calls to `curl` and n calls to jq, whereas only one call to each is required!!!

Answer (score 4):

In the jq program, `$i` refers to the jq variable `$i`, not the bash variable `$i`.

```sh
jq -r --arg i "$i" '.magic[] | select(.id == $i) | .name'
```